# Enums, overlapping values, C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, enums

Apologies in advance as I'm sure someone must have asked this before but I can't find it.

Just had a surprise, a colleague and I both added the same value in for an enum, and it compiled, e.g.

```
  enum MyEnum
  {
    mine = 1,
    his = 1
  }
```

Looks like C/C++ supports this also (?). Any reason for this behaviour, any cases where it's useful? I saw one case with difference human languages (one = 1, eins = 1, etc) but I'm not convinced

Thanks

Comment: So that maybe you could do this `enum MyEnum
  {
    [Obsolete]mine = 1,
    his = 1
  }`

Comment: Presumably, if you are making the values explicit you *care* about what those values are, so such conflicts should not occur. If you don't care about what value each member represents, you can just not make them explicit and no conflicts will occur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's take a simple example

```
enum PrivilegeLevel
{
    None,
    Reporter,
    Reviewer,
    Admin,
    DefaultForNewUser = None,
    DefaultForProjectOwner = Reviewer,
};
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea because of the binary versioning semantics of constants.

Comment: @crazyjul constants can't be versioned. If you change a constant (see, that's an oxymoron), all assemblies that made use of it ever are now broken because they still use the old value. You wouldn't change the value of pi, would you? But you might want to change the default privilege levels.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea behind enumerated types is to create new data types that can take on only a >restricted range of values.

What you did is legal and compiler is not ought to give any errors as enum represents just a constant. You are just giving your constant a logical name.

You can assign same values to to two or more enum constants when you need to separate the named constants. Say you have a color scheme both of which used the same basic color behind them, but the schemes need to be logically separated. Then you can use same values for enum constants. But still there are better ways to do that.

Comment: "If you assign the same value to two or more enum constants the whole purpose of enums is diminished." I disagree. The whole purpose of enums is to let you use names instead of magic numbers. I don't see how having two names with the same magic number is bad.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I wholeheartedly agree with your disagreement. There are times when aliases are a good thing.

Comment: I suppose it's no worse than a c++ typedef, just surprised at the time