# What does it mean to have overlapping enum values for AddressFamily (e.g. NS and Ipx)?

Tags: enums, network-protocols

I understand that `enum`s can have *overlapping* values, because at the end of the day enums are just `int`s and multiple *things* can have the *same* `int`. To me (and maybe this is the point that needs to be clarified) this means that those 2+ things that share the same `int` are the same for all intents and purposes.

The question, then, is:

1. What does it mean for the enum for [AddressFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.addressfamily?view=netframework-4.8) to have multiple protocols sharing the same enum value? For example, NS and Ipx are both six, but NS is "Address for Xerox NS protocols" and Ipx is "IPX or SPX address." Iso and Osi also share the same value as one another (7), but have respective meanings of "Address for ISO protocols" and "Address for OSI protocols."

Semi-related question: [Enums, overlapping values, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685816/enums-overlapping-values-c-sharp)

- This doesn't really seem to give a conclusive answer on why overlapping enums is *good*
- Also doesn't give a conclusive answer on what it really means in practice to have overlapping enum values.

Comment: Is your question why C# `enum`s can have the same value or why a particular example does?  Perhaps in the `AddressFamily` example some of the values are the same because at the end of the day they are just two sides of the same coin?

Comment: @MickyD It was more about why the particular example does. I was sharing the background of shared enum values so people wouldn't start re-answering that question, while also recognizing that maybe my fundamental understanding there was wrong somehow, leading my confusion to have a simple clarification. Doesn't seem like that's the case, though.

Comment: Not a problem good sir.   It's been a while since I have heard _"IPX"_.  Fond memories of my first LAN gaming :D

Comment: @MickyD good *ma'am :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#History) can also be called the ISO model. Indeed I learned it as the ISO-OSI Model. In part because that is the name of the organiation defining it. In part because you can also view it the other way around: Physical Layer is 7, Application is 1. At wich point you can flip the letters too.

As for **IPX and NS**, it is worth remembering that this enums purpose is "Specifies the addressing scheme that an instance of the Socket class can use."

As [wikipedia points out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internetwork_Packet_Exchange):

> "Internetwork Packet Exchange (IPX) is the network layer protocol in the IPX/SPX protocol suite. IPX is derived from Xerox Network Systems' IDP." I guess NS used to be it's own thing back in the day. But nowadays, even the followup IPX is hardly remembered.  It is hard to tell as I can not find "xerox ns protocol" on Wikipedia, but as IDP was from Xerox too makes that guess solid. Back in those days they were still doing the whole "Format War IX - Networking Edition".

Enums in such a case are usually fed into a switch/case block. I guess for this - in the actuall code - no differentiation was nessesary. However people still felt they needed two values in that Enum. In case any questions arose "where is NS/IPX?"

The only issues with having more then one Enum with the same value, is that getting to the Enum from the Integer is difficulty. However as Enumeartions were designed as Compile Time Constants, that is hardly an issue.

Comment: I think I found a Wikipedia Entry for NS now, under XNS. It apparently was a contemporary and adversary of the OSI model, but with only 5 layers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Network_Systems

Comment: Why not just incorporate your comment into your fine answer good sir? :)  Anyway, +1 to you.  Also **well done on being on top 0.18% [this week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2019-07-28/3346583#3346583)!!**